# AERSURFACE - How to calculate the inverse distance weighted geometric mean of surface caracteristics

Tags: qgis, inverse-distance-weighted, modelling, air-quality

I need to calculate the inverse distance weighted geometric mean of the cell values of different sectors within the 1-km radius from a weather station, using **QGIS**. I'll try to make it clearly below with images,

Generally speaking, I have a weather station located on a random terrain (values of surface roughness 1, 2, or 3, for instance). For each section (0-90º, 90º-180, or other angles), within a radius of 1 km, I should calculate the distance-weighted inverse geometric mean. The average is calculated from the values associated with each cell of the land cover class within the individual sector considering the radius of 1 km from the meteorological tower. Below there is a rough example.

[image]

The values associated with each cell in the grid are weighted based on the inverse distance from the weather tower. Following the following formula:

[image]

I have no clue whether I can use the raster calculator to have this IDW Geometric mean for each sector, and how to do this, or if there is any other processing tool that could help me with?

Obs: there is a USEPA free software that calculates this, AERSURFACE, but it requires to the raster to be in Albers Conic Equal Area projection of USA, and when I try to use other Albers Conic Equal Area projection for areas outside the USA, then it doesn't run, and I think I cannot use the USA projection for non-USA areas, because I would have big deformations.